# Click Handle on Jest

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, jest-fetch-mock

I am writing a test case using jest, but I am not able to get how to test click simulation if it is not button.
If it is button we write find('button), but what if we click on div and there are nested div

```
class Section extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            open: props.open,
            className: 'accordion-content accordion-close',
            headingClassName: 'accordion-heading'
        };

        this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
    }

    handleClick() {
        this.setState({
            open: !this.state.open
        });
    }

    render() {
        const { title, children } = this.props;
        const { open } = this.state;
        const sectionStateClassname = open
            ? styles.accordionSectionContentOpened
            : styles.accordionSectionContentClosed;

        return (
            <div className={styles.accordionSection}>
                <div
                    className={styles.accordionSectionHeading}
                    onClick={this.handleClick}
                    id="123"
                >
                    {title}
                </div>
                <div
                    className={`${
                        styles.accordionSectionContent
                    } ${sectionStateClassname}`}
                >
                    {children}
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

here is my jest test case

```
 test('Section', () => {
        const handleClick = jest.fn();
        const wrapper = mount(<Section  onClick={ handleClick} title="show more"/>)
        wrapper.text('show more').simulate('click')
        expect(handleClick).toBeCalled()
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can [find element by class](https://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/ReactWrapper/find.html):

```
wrapper.find('.' + styles.accordionSectionHeading).first().simulate('click')
```

Also, your component seems to not call prop `handleClick`. Instead, instance method is called, so something like this:

```
wrapper.instance().handleClick = jest.fn();
expect(wrapper.instance().handleClick).toBeCalled();
```

seems to be more correct.

Or, better, you can just check if state is changed

```
expect(wrapper.state('open')).toBeTruthy();
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi Alex, Thanks for the reply,  first solution gives error "Expected mock function to have been called, but it was not called".

Comment: Yeah, click simulate should be before expect

Comment: I  have done this but it is giving error? test('Section', () => {
  const handleClick = jest.fn();
  const wrapper = mount(<Section  onClick={ handleClick} title="show more"/>);
  wrapper.find('.' + styles.accordionSectionHeading).first().simulate('click');
  expect(handleClick).toBeCalled()
 });

Comment: yeah, your codebase doesn't call `props.handleClick`, `this.handleClick` is called instead.

Comment: @ShyamKumar why don't you check state instead?

Comment: Actually that's what I want to test that if we click , then it's state value is getting changes or not.

Comment: so you mean , I should test like this " test('Section', () => {
  const wrapper = mount(<Section  title="show more"/>)
  expect(wrapper.state('open')).toBeTruthy();
 });"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181468/discussion-between-shyam-kumar-and-alex).